# .net mysql odbc driver issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive migrated a site from an old server to a new windows server 2012 however I'm not getting this error message

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
Line 138:       OdbcCon.Open();
```

my code is

```
string sql = "SELECT files.file_id,files.file_name,files.size,files.date_added,users.title,users.forename,users.surname FROM files LEFT JOIN users ON files.upload_id = users.user_id WHERE files.owner_id IN(" + Request.QueryString["currentFiles"].ToString() + ") AND files.date_added >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' " + orderBy;
ConStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};" + "SERVER=serverip;" + "DATABASE=dbname;" + "UID=pfdownload;" + "PASSWORD=password" + "OPTION=3";
OdbcCon = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(ConStr);
OdbcCom = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, OdbcCon);
OdbcCon.Open();
```

I've installed the "mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-win32.msi"

Has anyone got any clues?

Comment: Sanitise your inputs, man! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Just to test the ODBC driver could you try to create a ODBC datasource using the mysql driver and this utility `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe`If you suceed in creating the connection and testing it, then the problem comes from your connectionString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by re-writing the code and using .net 4.5

Answer (score 2):

Try to install 64bit driver, w2K12 is a 64bit operating system